# Hover especifico para touch

Tags: javascript, css, css-hover, touch

Existe algum Hover do CSS para touch? Ou modo de emular um com javascript que apenas ative se for touch?

Comment: Como você acionaria o *hover* com *touch*? Na tela há o mouse, mas e com o dedo?

Comment: É porque no caso eu coloquei um link dentro de uma div que só aparece com hover e explica para onde vai, com o mouse ela aparece, ja no touch, se tocar, já vai direto no link, estou tendo dificuldade nesta parte.

Comment: E como é que você faz hover com o dedo sem tocar na tela ?

Comment: Tenta refazer a estrutura separando mouseover de clique.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer usando os eventos  ontouchend e o onmousemove dentro da div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha solução foi essa:

```js
window.onload = function(e){
 x = document.getElementById('x');
 
 x.addEventListener("touchstart", touch);
 x.addEventListener("touchend", touch);
 x.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse);
 x.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse);
 
 function touch(event){
  if(event.type == 'touchstart'){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
   x.style.background = 'blue';
            }, 200);
  }
  if(event.type == 'touchend'){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
    x.style.background = 'red'; 
   }, 3000);
  }
 }
 function mouse(event){
  if(event.type == 'mousemove'){ 
   x.style.background = 'blue';
  }
  if(event.type == 'mouseout'){
   x.style.background = 'red';
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#x{
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```